# Redirect a single page to another page with HTML

Tags: html, redirect

I am trying to redirect a single page on my website to another websites page. I don't want to redirect the entire website because all of it is still relevant; so http://new-website.com'" /> doesn't work.

Does anyone know an HTML code I can use to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

`<script>
    setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="http://blog.glocalade.org/2020/04/effecting-change-world-away.html";}, 0); 
</script>`